# PHP extension to modify default behavior

Tags: php, c, php-extension

**What I've Tried**

I've gone through the following PHP Extension tutorials: http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/ http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/ And all of them are great resources for adding new functions.

I've created a few simple extensions that add simple functions. Mostly `hello_world()` type extensions.  I've tried browsing the source code and everything but I just can't seem to find what I need.

**What I Need**

I need help or a point in the right direction on how I can change php functionality.  I'm trying to extend the syntax for a `foreach`.  This is more of a learning opportunity then I think changing the syntax for a `foreach` is a good idea.

1) How do I find the current implementation of `foreach` in the current PHP source code?
2) How do I write and extension to change it?

**The End Goal**

Every time I write an array where I want a unique set of numbers instead of putting the numbers in the values and doing an array search I put them in the keys and set the value as `true`.  When I do a `foreach` I don't care about the keys. so I want to create the following syntax:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => ) {
    // Do stuff here    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: foreach (array_keys($myArray) as $key) ?

Comment: An extension can't change the basic grammar of a language... It's like expecting the introduction of a new word, take _floobarb_ to change the tenses.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That's not generally true. True is that an extension cannot change the behaviour of PHP, and not more. (answered this 15 mins ago)

Comment: You can't do syntactic changes from an extension, but if you're okay with patching core, I have an article that explains the basics of how languages features are implemented: http://nikic.github.io/2012/07/27/How-to-add-new-syntactic-features-to-PHP.html

Comment: Thanks NikiC I haven't been able to find anything on it so far :) This helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change PHP's core behaviour using an extension. If you want to change the `foreach` loop you need to change core components of PHP and recompile it. It's up to you to find out what you'll have to change. (That's the fun)

However you may just doing this:

```
foreach (array_keys($myArray) as $key) {
    // Do stuff here    
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Doesn't it increase the memory because it creates a second array for the loop?

Comment: yes it does. if you care about memory just use `foreach($myArray as $key => $v) {` and don't care about `$v`.. (Me doing so)